# This says cessation of patent right does that mean its expired?

Tags: cn202615055

https://www.google.com/patents/CN202615055U?cl=en 
is this expired, i know patents last 20 yearsbut if its cessation does that void it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a utility model, which can last at maximum 10 years from the filing date. But this is not the reason of cessation of rights. The owner stopped paying the renewal fees after 2012.